# Is it ok to group old sport clubs into a single entry in Form N-400 (Application for Naturalization)?

Tags: usa, citizenship, paperwork

Form N-400 (Application for Naturalization) asks me to list ask the clubs I participated in:

> Provide information about your membership, involvement, or association with an organization, association, fund, foundation, party, club, society, or similar group in the United States or in any other location in the world.

I was in about a dozen of sport clubs when I was a kid/teenager, which was over a decade ago, and I can't remember the names nor the exact membership periods.

Is it ok to group sport clubs in Form N-400 (Application for Naturalization) into just one entry, or should I list them one by one? I don't even remember the name of most of them, nor the exact membership years.

E.g., my thought was to have one single entry "Misc. sport clubs", and describe it in the form approximately as follows "I was part of several sport clubs in France during my childhood and teenager years. The sports were [x, y, z, etc.]. I don't remember the exact years nor the names of the clubs, but it was between [year] and [year] and clubs were solely sportive".

Answer (score 1):

Is it OK? You'll have to ask the USCIS officer during the interview. Or, more likely, they'll tell you if they don't think it is Ok.

This is one of these questions that are designed to later be used to annul your citizenship based on fraudulent application. If 50 years from now the government uncovers that you've been a member of the "Former Nazi Concentration Camp Guards Club in Northern Marseilles" or "Gentlemen's Club for Murderers and Rapists in Southern Calais" and you didn't disclose that club - you'll get bounced out of the US. If they find out that you missed one of your kindergarten activities there - they probably wouldn't care.

Bottom line, try to disclose the information available to you in the most truthful manner.